# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n \mod 7)10^{-n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, summation, modular-arithmetic, power-series

> Is the number $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n \mod 7)10^{-n!}$$ algebraic ?
>   Here, $n \mod 7$ means the natural number is between 0 to 6 which is congruent to n modulo 7.

Justify your explanations, as I don't have any idea what to do with it? It's the first time I have ever seen modulo in series.

DO I need to find the sum which converges to **0.12003** and I don't know how to derive this result. Or is there any other way to find the answer of the question asked.

**My questions:**

How to do the question given in yellow bar?

**Extra credit: How to derive it's convergence values, I know it converges rapidly if we take upto n only 9-10 terms I guess**  But is there nay more general method ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number

Comment: An algebraic number (of degree $d$) cannot be approximated very well with rational numbers ($p/q$ using a tolerance which is $\sim 1/q^d$, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation ) but your number is. For the extra credit, what are the "convergence values"?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. The reason for this is something called irrationality measure, which measures how closely a number can be approximated by rationals. See here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html

There is a theorem that states that non-rational algebraic numbers have an irrationality measure of two (rationals have measure one). But the number you have given has infinite irrationality measure (try proving this once you’ve read the definition!)